# Returning NSNull from actionForLayer:forKey

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, delegates, calayer

If I implement the CALayer delegate method `actionForLayer:forKey` I can return `[NSNull null]` to force the CALayer to not animate any changes. Unfortunately, `[NSNull null]` doesn't implement the `CAAction` delegate and XCode kicks out the following warning:

> warning: class 'NSNull' does not implement the 'CAAction' protocol

Here is the method code:

```
- (id<CAAction>)actionForLayer:(CALayer *)theLayer
                        forKey:(NSString *)theKey {
 //This disables the animations when moving things around
 //Also, don't animate the selection box. It was doing weird things
 if(undoGroupStarted || theLayer == self.selectionBox) {
  return [NSNull null];
 } else {
  return nil;
 }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is returning `[NSNull null]` bad behavior? If so, what is another way to do what I am trying to do here? If not, how do I make the compiler happy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "CoreAnimation Programming Guide" section [Defined Search Pattern for Action Keys](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Actions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006095-SW7) addresses this. They `CALayer` delegate can return `nil` to specify that it doesn't handle the action, but that the search should continue. It can also return `[NSNull null]` to specify that the action should not be handled (that is, the search should stop).

In the `CALayer` header, you'll see a bit more detail about how this is handled:

> If any of these steps results in a non-nil action object, the
>   following steps are ignored. If the final result is an instance of
>   NSNull, it is converted to `nil'.

To make the compiler accept this, you can simply cast:

```
return (id <CAAction>)[NSNull null]; // Prevent the action from animating
```

Comment: Yeah, that got rid of the compiler warning. Something makes me pause at casting NSNull... but it obviously isn't going to cause any problems since I have been returning NSNull this whole time without an issue. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Judging by Apple's CAAction documentation, the only built-in class that implements the CAAction protocol is CAAnimation (and its subclasses, of course). The compiler is expecting a return value that implements CAAction, so yes, returning [NSNull null] will not work. Do you really need to use this delegate method, as opposed to removing animations from the layer using `[layer removeAllAnimations]` or `[layer removeAnimationForKey:]`?

It seems wasteful, but if you absolutely have to use the delegate method, perhaps you could return a "blank" animation object:

```
return [CAAnimation animation];
```

Also, do you need to disable this animation permanently, or only in specific circumstances? If you don't need to permanently override the animation, you can use a CATransaction to disable animation for individual method calls, as documented here in the [Core Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Transactions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006096-SW6).

Comment: I only need to disable the animation under specific circumstances and the disable will behave the exact same way to a dozen or so layers. Using the delegate allows me to switch their behavior when the circumstances appear. I will try the blank animation to see if it works. I don't think the CATransaction will work but I will look at it again.